# accessing list of companies in Business central sanbox on cloud (api v2.0) with a super user

Tags: api, integration, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I set up 3 sandbox environments in the cloud then I try to access one of the API as below (using basic authentication wit Web service Access Key) and it works in browser:

- **Test1** is the name of my environment

  - https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Test1/api/v1.0/
  - https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Test1/api/v1.0/#metadata

everything is fine so far, but if I try to get the list of companies I get the below error although I’m superuser in all environments/companies:
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Test1/api/v1.0/companies

the response:

```
{
error: {
code: “Authentication_InvalidCredentials”,
message: “The server has rejected the client credentials. CorrelationId: f32a193e-5426-44f9-ab18-4e331950fe63.”
}
}
```

FYI:
I’m sure my credentials are correct, because if I change them then I can’t get the #metadata.

any idea?

Comment: Are you calling the API from a tool like Postman or from a program you're developing? I would start to look at how the authorization header is sent.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer , here is what I done:

- find the id of your organiation in azure
- inject it in the api url after version number
- you need to register a new app in Azure "app registeration" in order to get an  endpoint for authentication later-on
- using that endpoint to get a "Bearer Token"
- using the bearer token in http headers and call the below API

  https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{your organization GUID ID}/Test1/api/v1.0/companies